# How to plot the solution of polynomial system in 3d using contour3d

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

If I try to

```
h = x^2 + 2 y^2 + 3 z^2 - 1;
s = ContourPlot3D[{h == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},  
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 40]],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, BaseStyle -> 14]
```

Then everything works fine, and I get the expected ellipsoid in 3d.[image]

Now I would like to do the same but in a higher dimension. I want to solve a polynomial in 5 variables, namely

```
h = x^2 + 2 y^2 + 3 z^2  + 2 a^2 + b^2- 1;
```

and see what happens in the lower dimension (3d) in terms of x,y,z. So I try to evaluate the same line as before

```
s = ContourPlot3D[{h == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},  
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 40]],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, BaseStyle -> 14]
```

But it does not work.
I get the same Input line as output and no plots.

I have no idea what is wrong. Can you explain why? and how to get this working?

Comment: You will need to assign values to `a` and `b`. Otherwise `ContourPlot` is left with a symbolic expression that it cannot plot.

Comment: Hi Marco, shouldn't a and b posses values from the solutions of the polynomial equation?

Comment: There are *many* possible values `a` and `b` could take depending on the  values of `x` `y` `z` and vice-versa. The complete set of solutions would then be an ellipsoid in `x` `y` `z`, which isn't a surface, but a 3d region and that's not the function of `ContourPlot`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. As I can imagine, the solution will be a region in the fifth dimensional space (i.e values for x,y,z, b and a). I'm interested in looking at the values of x, y and z that are in the solution set by a plot in 3D. This means that I want to take all the values of x, y and z from this set (and forget about a, b), then put all these values together in a 3D plot. Are you saying that this will still be an ellipsoid like the example above in my question?

Comment: No, not quite. In the first example you have the *two-dimensional boundary* of an ellipsoid in *three-dimensional space*. With 5 (or even with 4) *real valued* variables with *positive coefficients* you will get the *entire* ellipsoid.